# Annoying behaviour when I'm counting checked elements of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form with many checkboxes. Somewhere in my client's code I need to check if a given checkbox is really checked returning a boolean value. I've googled around and supposed this solution as optimal:

```
$("input[@id=checkboxId]:checked").length>0
```

This works fine if every checkbox in the page is unchecked, while it's completly unusefull otherwise. Why this happens? Why other checkboxes interfear with this behaviour even specifyng the `id` of interested checkbox?

I prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rzHZ/) of this behaviour. In this example you can notice, that, if the second checkbox is checked, console output will be always `true`, while if I uncheck the second checkbox I have alternate `true/false` value.

Where I wrong how can I fix this (I have jQuery 1.4 on this client and I can't upgrade)?

Comment: console.log($("#testableCheckbox:checked").length>0)
works fine.. the @ is the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `@` symbol from your attribute selector.(`@attr` was removed from jQuery 1.3)

It should be `$("input[id=checkboxId]:checked").length > 0`

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2rzHZ/2/)***

or simply `$("#checkboxId:checked").length > 0`

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

*Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the “@” symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.*

Comment: Just a curiosity: where his @ came from? I can't remember any time I did @attr ..  Or any docs mentioning it.

Comment: @enapupe - until jQuery 1.2, @attr is the syntax. `@` was removed from  v1.3

Comment: That was a long time huh? 2008? jQuery 1.2 'New Wave Javascript'

Comment: @enapupe yep it was. Sep '07

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of this method

```
console.log($(this).is(':checked'))
```

or

```
console.log($('#checkboxId').is(':checked'))
```